# MySql collecting database only English but not other

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8, collation, encode

I have a comment section and submission form that any of my member can submit.
If my member post in English I will receive an email update and the comment will be post no problem in English.  But if they use other than English such an example of Thai language.   Then what happen all the words let say for example `สวัสดี` it will appear as `??????`

I don't know why, but I went to check on my `php.ini` file and the unicode/encoded setted to UTF8 and also on the MySQL collation setted to UTF8 as well.  I make sure the meta setted to UTF8 as well on the .html/.php files, but still causing the same problem.

Any suggestion what else I missed to configure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that what is causing the problem

in `php.ini`

line `mbstring.internal_encoding`it was setted to something else so I setted it to UTF-8 then magical! now everything worked!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using [multibyte safe string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) or you might be losing your UTF-8 encoding.

**From the PHP mbstring manual:**

> While there are many languages in
>   which every necessary character can be
>   represented by a one-to-one mapping to
>   an 8-bit value, there are also several
>   languages which require so many
>   characters for written communication
>   that they cannot be contained within
>   the range a mere byte can code (A byte
>   is made up of eight bits. Each bit can
>   contain only two distinct values, one
>   or zero. Because of this, a byte can
>   only represent 256 unique values (two
>   to the power of eight)). Multibyte
>   character encoding schemes were
>   developed to express more than 256
>   characters in the regular bytewise
>   coding system.
>
> When you manipulate (trim, split,
>   splice, etc.) strings encoded in a
>   multibyte encoding, you need to use
>   special functions since two or more
>   consecutive bytes may represent a
>   single character in such encoding
>   schemes. Otherwise, if you apply a
>   non-multibyte-aware string function to
>   the string, it probably fails to
>   detect the beginning or ending of the
>   multibyte character and ends up with a
>   corrupted garbage string that most
>   likely loses its original meaning.
>
> mbstring provides multibyte specific
>   string functions that help you deal
>   with multibyte encodings in PHP. In
>   addition to that, mbstring handles
>   character encoding conversion between
>   the possible encoding pairs. mbstring
>   is designed to handle Unicode-based
>   encodings such as UTF-8 and UCS-2 and
>   many single-byte encodings for
>   convenience

Comment: So basically I need to install the MB_Safe_string to my php.ini right if I understand it right?